# Webtoon where the protagonist is stuck in a barrier-like dungeon, after trying to bring his mother some food

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for a webtoon where the protagonist was on his way to buying his mom some sort of food that she was asking for.

He ends up stuck in the lvl 1 dungeon that's basically an enclosed prison. There he has to fight this big monster over and over. He dies many times, but also kills the same monster. Due to an error in the system, he is stuck here for years.

He slowly goes insane in this dungeon, but eventually manages to break out. He breaks out by literally breaking the barrier down. He comes out to a war-like scene where monsters are running around. His number one thought is to get his mom the food that he said he was going to get her before getting sucked into the dungeon.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Please take your time to visit out [help] and take the [tour]. You've tagged this as a manga, but described it s a webtoon which normally indicates an online animation. Which is closer to the work in question?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - The OP was probably referring to South Korean digital comics (basically the Korean version of manga), which are [also known as webtoons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webtoon) or manhwa. There's an argument to be made for having a separate manhwa tag on this site, but we generally just tag these as manga.

Comment: Ah I didn't know it was called webtoons. I'm more familiar with that being used for things like [Weebl and Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weebl_and_Bob).

Answer (score 4):

The Manhwa is called "Limit Breaker"
The mc is working in a super market where he suddenly hear a BANG he goes outside to see what happened and sees monster outside of his world he then dies and get transported to the awakening zone where he gets to unlock his skill to beat the monster. He finishes the awakening but their was an ERROR where he couldn't get out so he just keep getting killed by the monster but since in the awakening zone everytime he dies he gets revived same goes for the monster in the zone. He then gets stuck there for 3000 years which is 10 years in the real world since the time in the awakening zone is much faster then the real world then he suddenly manages to get out by breaking the awakening world.